# React component not rendering after useRef object gets updated

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I have the following component which should generate a d3 bar chart and update it every 3 seconds. It receives a dataset from its parent every 3 seconds. 
Right now, it generates the chart but it does not update it. I can confirm that the dataset is updated and received every 3 seconds and then useEffect is triggered. 
I have tried to set intervals and replace useRef but it did not work.

Any idea? Any other way I should structure this kind of component to generate D3 elements?
Let me know if you need more info. Thanks

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

import * as d3 from "d3";

export const BarChart = ({ dataset }) => {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (dataset && dataset[0].valor) {
      const svgHeight = 200;
      const svgWidth = 350;
      const barPadding = 30;
      const barWidth = svgWidth / dataset.length;

      const svgElement = d3
        .select(ref.current)
        .attr("width", svgWidth)
        .attr("height", svgHeight);

      svgElement
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("y", d => svgHeight - d.valor - 40)
        .attr("x", (d, i) => i * barWidth)
        .attr("height", d => d.valor)
        .attr("width", barWidth - barPadding)
        .attr("fill", d => (d.valor > 47 ? "blue" : "red"));
    }
  }, [dataset]);

  return (
    <div>
      <svg ref={ref} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The issue was not related to useRef but to the d3 code that I wrote, instead of using .enter().append('rect') I should have used .join(). See below:

```
svgElement
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(dataset)
        .join("rect")
        .attr("y", d => svgHeight - d.valor - 40)
        .attr("x", (d, i) => i * barWidth)
        .attr("height", d => d.valor)
        .attr("width", barWidth - barPadding)
        .attr("fill", d => (d.valor > 47 ? "blue" : "red"));
    }
```